# Given three non abelian group of order 8,two must be isomorphic.

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism

True or false:

Given three non abelian group of order $8$,two must be isomorphic.

**Solution:**

Theorem : A non-Abelian group of order $8$ is isomorphic  either to $D_4$ or  $Q_8$.

I Think it is true.

Comment: It is true, and a good exercise too.

Comment: Are you sure  @Olivier Bégassat

Comment: Well, I concur with @Olivier; it *is* true, and it *is* a good exercise. Don't let anyone spoil your fun by doing it for you.

Comment: Hint: as a 2-group G is nilpotent and so has a non trivial center. Consider how this center can be extended.

Comment: @Nimda, I have a feeling that someone asking a question at this level isn't going to know about nilpotent, center, or extending.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, but it is not always easy to evaluate the background of the OP if he has no bio and only gives the background of the question but not the context of the course that he's following. But I'll try anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Show that if $G$ has an element of order $4$ and ***doesn't*** have an element of order 8, then $$\begin{cases}|G| = 8\\G=\langle a,b\rangle\\a^4 = e\\b^2 = a^u\\ba = a^sb\end{cases}$$

Where $u = 0,2$ and $s = 1,3$.

The first part comes by considering $H = \langle a\rangle$ and take $b \in G- H$ and consider the group $K$ spanned by $a$ and $b$, (Use Lagrange's Theorem.)

To define $u,s$ check the possibilities for $u,s \in \lbrace0,1,2,3\rbrace$ and remember that G does not have an element of order $8$.

The cases you want are
$$\begin{cases}|G| = 8\\G=\langle a,b\rangle\\a^4 = e\\b^2 = e\\ba = a^3b\end{cases}$$
and
$$\begin{cases}|G| = 8\\G=\langle a,b\rangle\\a^4 = e\\b^2 = a^2\\ba = a^3b\end{cases}$$

Comment: @ShanayaSharma So did you get to prove that?